# Перенос при объединении строки

Tags: python

```
def nnn(name, url):
   u = "@"+url[-2] +"."+url[-1]
   name0 = name.split(" ")
   if len(name0) == 1:
      name3 = name.replace(' ', '')+u
      print(name3)
```

Есть такая функция, в нее я передаю 2 переменные. провожу кое какие манипуляции и в итоге объединяю `name` и `u` . Ожидаю увидеть строку `name@url` но вместо этого получаю

```
name
@url
```

как я понимаю проблема в `replace(' ', '')` как это можно исправить?

Comment: а зачем там это ? имя может с пробелом быть ? name3 = name+u и не париться

Comment: там имя+фамилия между ними пробел

Comment: @insolor да, вполне на меня похоже...